# Python Data frames Compare and Assign

Tags: python, dataframe

I've got two python dataframes, one with the 3 columns (range and probability)

```
   Low     High     Probability
0  -0.6030 -0.5350  0.001326
1  -0.5350 -0.4700  0.000000
2  -0.4700 -0.4050  0.002653
3  -0.4050 -0.3400  0.001326
4  -0.3400 -0.2750  0.001326
```

and the other with values

```
   x         y     
0  -0.62
1  -0.12
2  -0.22
3  -0.45
4  -0.39
```

How can I compare the X values against the bins in the first dataframe to assign a corresponding y (probability) value?

I've tried np.dot (misuse of the intended function if I am correct) as well as dictonary with a range key.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact function you are trying to apply? Please include a more descriptive formula.

Comment: Im function agnostic here, I just really need to have some sort v-lookup type function to assign each 'x' a 'y' value based on the bin it falls into

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want to merge so that `x` is between `Low` and `High`.

You can use `merge_asof`:

```
# merge on Low (requires both keys to be sorted)
(pd.merge_asof(df2.reset_index().sort_values(by='x'),
               df1.sort_values(by='Low'),
               left_on='x',
               right_on='Low',
              )
   # sort again on original order
   .set_index('index').sort_index()
   # ensure that x ≤ High and mask the non matching values
   .assign(y=lambda d: d['Probability'].where(d['x'].le(d['High'])))
   # drop the intermediary columns
   .drop(columns=df1.columns)
 )
```

Output:

```
          x         y
index                
0     -0.62       NaN
1     -0.12       NaN
2     -0.22       NaN
3     -0.45  0.002653
4     -0.39  0.001326
```

Comment: Because the data is date sensitive I'm not sure I can sort by 'x' values

Comment: @grandpa the sorting is temporary, you don't have a choice with `merge_asof` anyway, the data **must** be sorted on the key